# Getting X-Forwarded-for request header too long when accessing an api using nginx configured using docker

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup my application. I am getting following content logged in my nginx image logs

```
2023-08-18 11:41:06 172.18.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2023:06:11:06 +0000] "POST /assets/6/meters.json?gridserver=true HTTP/1.0" 400 635 "http://localhost/assets/6/meters" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1"
```

Its been logged multiple times in the logs. I am getting following message in error log file:

```
2023/08/18 06:11:05 [info] 30#30: *1365 client sent too long header line: "X-Forwarded-For: 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172..." while reading client request headers, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /assets/6/meters.json?gridserver=true HTTP/1.0", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/assets/6/meters"
```

My nginx config details are as follows:

```
    upstream app {
        # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined in config/puma.rb
        # updating path to match default PUMA_PATH in env
        server unix:///srv/www/apps/bin/puma/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

server {
    listen 80;
    # listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name localhost;
    root /srv/www/apps/revenue_accounting/public;
    
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    # Global error log
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log info;

    location @app {
        internal;
        resolver 127.0.0.11;
        
        # Access log for this server block
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        if ($args ~* "(.*gridserver=true.*)") {
            proxy_pass http://grid-services$request_uri;
        }

        if ($args ~* "(.*traceserver=true.*)") {
            proxy_pass http://gora-services:3001$request_uri;
        }

        # TODO: Figure out how to pass storybook URLs to port 6006
        # if ($args ~* "(.*/storybook.*)") {
        #     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6006$request_uri;
        # }

        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        
        # set timeout to 10 minutes
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
        proxy_send_timeout 600s;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I tried changing value for X-Forwarded-for but didn't helped

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. Let me know if you figure this out!

Comment: @BryantRockoff No I didn't got any solution for that. The issue was coming in my windows machine. When I tried the same setup on mac it worked. No idea how it could be os specific issue.